# a question on $\epsilon$-chain sequences

Tags: general-topology, analysis, dynamical-systems

Suppose $X$ is a compact metric space and $ f : X \to X$ is a homeomorphism.

By an $\epsilon$-chain from $x$ to $y$ in $X$ we mean a finite sequence $x_0 ,x_1 ... , x_k$ in $X$ with $x_0=x$ and $x_k=y$ such that :
\begin{align}
d(f(x_n) , x_{n+1})< \epsilon \; , \; n=0 ,..., k-1
\end{align}
a point $x \in X$ is said to be chain recurrent of $f$ , if for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $\epsilon$-chain from $x$ to $x$.

Now suppose $f: [a,b] \to [a,b]$ is a strictly increasing homeomorphism which $a$ , $b$ are fixed points of $f$.

Now if $x \not\in Fix(f)$ then we may assume $f(x)>x$, take $\epsilon=\dfrac{|f(x)-x|}{2}$. I want to prove that there is no $\epsilon$-chain from $x$ to $x$ with this $\epsilon$.

By contradiction I suppose by this $\epsilon$ we have an $\epsilon$-chain so we have a finite sequence like $x=x_0 ,x_1 ... x_k=x$ such that :
\begin{align}
d(f(x_n) , x_{n+1})<\epsilon , \; n=0 ,..., k-1
\end{align}
I can't reach a statement which contradicts my assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x=x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_k=x$ is an $\epsilon$-chain, where of course $k>0$. Clearly $x_1>f(x_0)-\epsilon=x+\epsilon$. In particular, $x_1>x$, so $$f(x_1)>f(x)=x+2\epsilon\,,$$ and $$x_2>f(x_1)-\epsilon>x+\epsilon\,.$$ In general, suppose that $x_i>x$ for some $i\in\{1,\ldots,k-1\}$; then $$f(x_i)>f(x)=x+2\epsilon\,,$$ so $$x_{i+1}>f(x_i)-\epsilon>x+\epsilon\,.$$ By induction it follows that $x=x_k>x+\epsilon$, which is absurd.

Comment: Why is it trivial that $x_1>f(x_0) - \epsilon$ ?
How could you write $f(x_0)-\epsilon=x+\epsilon$ ?

Comment: @Reza: Since we’re assuming that $f(x)>x$, we have $2\epsilon=f(x)-x$, so $f(x)-\epsilon=x+\epsilon$. And $|f(x_0)-x_1|<\epsilon$, so $f(x_0)-\epsilon<x_1<f(x_0)+\epsilon$.